# Audio noise on output of PCM1789

Tags: pcb, audio, noise, dac, esp32

I am developing a Bluetooth adapter to be able to listen to music from my phone in my car. I am doing that with ESP32, from which the audio data is sent to PCM1789 which converts it to the analog signal. I have made 5 different versions of my PCB each one trying to fix the main problem which is the noise I get on the output. I am completely sure it is not the speaker's fault, because it plays clearly when the radio is set to FM. I do not have an oscilloscope that could help me find the cause of the issue, but maybe someone will have an idea what I could change in my design to make it better.

The sample of noise I get (sorry for the microphone quality, but I hope you will still be able to hear it).
https://www31.zippyshare.com/v/tprlozZL/file.html

What I have tried already:

- I made separate analog and digital grounds that have the common point at the input pin. (I am not sure if the capacitors that work with analog current should use analog or digital ground, I made the connection to the analog one).
- I added separate linear regulator that switches 12-14V to 5V for the analog power supplies of DAC.
- I have tried to implement a low pass filter with 1nF capacitor and 4K7 resistor to see it it gets better but the difference wasn't too big.

One thing that I also checked is that the noise exists already on the output pin of PCM1789 (I touched the output pins with radio's input pins to test it).

PCM1789 documentation's typical application:
[image]

Schematic of my PCB:
[image]

PCB design:
[image]

Comment: But as the DAC output is just wired to a connector, how are you connecting it to the car radio input? Since you don't show that part, I bet that is the problem.

Comment: @Justme My device is emulating CD changer. I just connect my output pins to the audio input pins on the car's radio, where the CD changer was connected originally.

Comment: OK, sounds problematic already, but you don't say how exactly do you connect it, where which way and how are the R+ R- L+ and L- from DAC connected to the CD changer input port?

Comment: @Justme Radio has R+ R- L+ L- input ports that should be connected to the CD changer. I have a goldpin connector (visible on the top of PCB layout) on my PCB. I use breadboard wires to connect each pin directly to the coresponding pin on the radio.

Comment: Which radio is it and where is the pinout of the connector available? Are you sure it takes in a differential input? Also your DAC output stage is missing buffers and filtering, even if you want a differential connection.

Comment: @Justme it is a radio from BMW E46, named CD53. This is the pinout I am using (bottom left connector) [link](https://www.bimmerfest.com/attachments/auxin-2-jpg.552761). I am an amateur of electronics and did not consider filters and buffers yet, but as I saw a very common project using the same DAC to a previous generation of that car, there also wasn't any filter or buffer.

Comment: The routing for your "decoupling" caps C6, C8 & C9 is just awful (sorry). Each pin of each cap must be directly connected to the corresponding pin on the PCM1789 with a short (preferably fat) trace. The way you have them routed now they're not able to do their job in any useful way.

Comment: @brhans thanks to mentioning that. Now I read how it should look like and I have tried that by adding some short wires to the device to try if there will be an improvement, but nothing changed about the sound quality

Comment: 1. are you testing in your car? Generally you should start by getting the th9ing working reliably on the bench, to reduce the chance of external interference. Also you can hear better. 2. short the inputs to ground and see if the output is quiet. 3. Do a test with a sine wave of around 300Hz, to see if you hear noise or interference.  Once you did these steps and got things sounding good, do a listening test with music.

Comment: By the way I'm not hearing your recording as being particularly noisy. It sounds like there is no bass and not much treble, very coloured but if you are recording the speaker output with your phone or something that is how it will sound. It's really not possible to evaluate the quality of an audio circuit like this. You can use a PC with a decent soundcard to generate tones, and evaluate the noise of your circuit with no input. This kind of measurement, even done in a basic way, will get you 500 times further than ad-hoc subjective listening tests on source material of unknown provenance.

Comment: @danmcb 
1. I am testing it in my room, I have a power adapter that provides 12v and with that I run the radio and my device. 
2. When I short input with ground it is completely silent, no noise there.
3. I made a new recording with 300Hz wave. It is buzzing. [link](https://www26.zippyshare.com/v/uNh7K147/file.html)

Comment: ok. Is the 12V power adaptor a switcher? Normally this would show up with s/c input, but it could be that switching noise on the power rail is messing with the analogue side. I couldn't hear any noise to speak of on your recording.

Comment: @danmcb yes, it is a switcher. But would it be possible that it is the source of the problem if radio plays music clearly when switched to FM mode? If so, then I will test it in my car if it gets better there. About the recording - have you heard the recording I put a link to in my previous comment? It is easier to hear it there.

Comment: @danmcb I have now tried it with a 12V battery I had in my garage. It seems to be much better, but the buzzing is still there

Comment: if the radio plays more clearly in FM it sounds like interference for sure. AM is much more susceptible to that.